# Is -[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:] additive and does it overwrite values?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

In other words, must I call `registerDefaults` in only one location in my app (e.g. when it starts up), or can I register defaults on an as-needed basis?

If it is additive, what happens when I try overwriting a value?

For example, given the following code...

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"a": @1}];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"b": @2}];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"b": @3}];
```

... what will the final defaults dictionary be?

1. `@{@"b": @3}` (replacive)
2. `@{@"a": @1, @"b": @3}` (additive, overwrite values)
3. `@{@"a": @1, @"b": @2}` (additive, don't overwrite values)
4. Crash, since @"b" is already defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2. It is **additive**, and **overwrites** values.

Example:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"a": @1}];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"b": @2}];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"b": @3}];
NSAssert([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"a"] == 1, @"");
NSAssert([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"b"] == 3, @"");
```

The ultimate dictionary is:

```
@{@"a": @1, @"b": @3}
```

Thus, you can call it as many times as necessary.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults:):

> Adds the contents of the specified dictionary to the registration domain.

Comment: `registerDefaults` does not overwrite real values. An explicit value always takes precedence over a default. The default value is only returned if no explicit value has been set.

Comment: Yes, this answer is a bit misleading at first glance e.g. if you did `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: 3 forKey: @"b"]` instead of the second "b" `registerDefaults` call, and then called `registerDefaults` to change the value for "b" to something else, it would have `3` in the output.

Comment: Although technically the answer is not inaccurate.

Comment: This question/answer is all about `registerDefaults` and nowhere is `setInteger` nor any of the other `set` methods mentioned nor called. It's about understanding how `registerDefaults` works.